# Parse on AWS Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server

I have recently migrated my Parse.com service over to AWS Elastic Beanstalk running the Parse Server project from Github. Everything seems to be working fine except when I try to perform a query in Cloud Code.

Whenever I try to run a `Parse.Query` command I get the following exception at runtime.

```
Uncaught internal server error. [ReferenceError: atom is not defined] ReferenceError: atom is not defined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js:559:78
    at Array.map (native)
    at transformConstraint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js:556:29)
    at transformQueryKeyValue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js:193:7)
    at transformWhere (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js:215:15)
    at MongoStorageAdapter.find (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoStorageAdapter.js:321:59)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Controllers/DatabaseController.js:827:33
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:102:28
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
```

Here is a sample of the Cloud Code I'm running. I must mention this code worked perfectly when hosted on Parse.com.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getNumberOfUnreadMessages", function(request, response) {

  var currentUser = request.params.user;

  console.log("[getNumberOfUnreadMessages] Get User: " + JSON.stringify(currentUser));

  var query = new Parse.Query("messages");
  query.containedIn("toUser", [currentUser]);
  query.equalTo("read", false);

  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      console.log('[getNumberOfUnreadMessages] Results: ' + results.length);
      response.success(results.length);

    },
    error: function(e) {
      response.error("[getNumberOfUnreadMessages] Error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the issue has nothing todo with the server configuration. It was simply that I was trying to perform a Parse.Query.or function with a full object as apposed to a pointer to an object. Annoying that parse didn't give me a proper error, but in this case there is no bug.